# Is it possible to limit TextCtrl to accept numbers only in wxPython?

Tags: wxpython, textctrl

I want to have a text control that only accepts numbers. (Just integer values like 45 or 366)

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`IntCtrl`, `Masked Edit Control`, and `NumCtrl` are all designed to do just this, with different levels of control.  Checkout the wx demo under "More Windows/Controls" to see how they work.

(Or, if you're instead really looking forward to doing this directly with a raw TextCtrl, I think you'd want to catch EVT_CHAR events, test the characters, and call evt.Skip() if it was an allowed character.)

Answer (score 10):

I had to do something similar, checking for alphanumeric codes. The tip on EVT_CHAR was the right thing:

```
class TestPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent, -1)
        self.entry = wx.TextCtrl(self, -1)
        self.entry.Bind(wx.EVT_CHAR, self.handle_keypress)

    def handle_keypress(self, event):
        keycode = event.GetKeyCode()
        if keycode < 255:
            # valid ASCII
            if chr(keycode).isalnum():
                # Valid alphanumeric character
                event.Skip()
```

Comment: how will it work for cases when user presses del button or arrow buttons?

Answer (score 1):

You can try `IntCtrl`, `EVT_CHAR`, or implement a new/existing validator (like [IntValidator](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.lib.intctrl.IntValidator-class.html)). Validators can be used to validate a field (useful when trying to validate multiple things on a dialog/panel) and they can also be used with EVT_CHAR to restrict input in a field.

Answer (score 1):

As other answers note, it's possible to do this with an `EVT_CHAR` handler. You'll want to call `event.Skip()` for the characters you want to let through, and not call it for the ones you want to block. One nuance is that you probably also want to call `event.Skip()` for tab characters; pressing tab triggers the `EVT_CHAR` event, and if you don't call `event.Skip()`, you'll effectively disable tab traversal between `TextCtrl`s.

Here's a minimal application showing two `TextCtrl`s that accept integer or decimal numbers, with working tab traversal:

```
import wx

app = wx.App()

frame = wx.Frame(None, -1, 'simple.py')
panel = wx.Panel(frame)
text_ctrl_1 = wx.TextCtrl(panel, value='123')
text_ctrl_2 = wx.TextCtrl(panel, value='456', pos=(0, 30))

def block_non_numbers(event):
    key_code = event.GetKeyCode()

    # Allow ASCII numerics
    if ord('0') <= key_code <= ord('9'):
        event.Skip()
        return

    # Allow decimal points
    if key_code == ord('.'):
        event.Skip()
        return

    # Allow tabs, for tab navigation between TextCtrls
    if key_code == ord('\t'):
        event.Skip()
        return

    # Block everything else
    return

text_ctrl_1.Bind(wx.EVT_CHAR, block_non_numbers)
text_ctrl_2.Bind(wx.EVT_CHAR, block_non_numbers)

frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: You'll probably also want to enable backspace, del, left-right: `if key_code in (8, 127, 314, 316):
            event.Skip()
            return` Note, the values may be platform dependent.

Comment: @jake77 I believe those keys don't trigger `EVT_CHAR` at all (and so checking for them in an `EVT_CHAR` handler is unnecessary), though I'll confirm later.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted the same but for floats, so I used the following method in the class:

```
 def force_numeric(self, event, edit):
    raw_value =  edit.GetValue().strip()
    keycode = event.GetKeyCode()
    if keycode < 255:
        print('keycode:', keycode,'chr(keycode) ', chr(keycode))
        if chr(keycode).isdigit() or chr(keycode)=='.' and '.' not in raw_value:
            print('skip')
            event.Skip()
```

to register the event in the constructor:

```
    item = wx.TextCtrl(self.panel, -1, str(pose_config['locref_stdev']))
    item.Bind(wx.EVT_CHAR, lambda event: self.force_numeric(event, item))
```

Modifying the answer above

Comment: I would add key=8 support to ablt to delete charachers
```
if chr(keycode).isdigit() or keycode == 8 or chr(keycode) == '.' and '.' not in raw_value:
```

Answer (score 0):

NumCtrl has some weird quirks to me. Here is my attempt to create a Number control based on EVT_CHAR and keycode.

This control allow numbers as well as all special keycode (ctrl combo, arrow key, backspace etc...), so that copy-paste, undo-redo, select-all etc still works. It will only block other printable characters (using [string.printable](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string-constants)) and unicode characters (using [WXK_NONE](https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.KeyEvent.html?highlight=keycode#wx.KeyEvent.GetKeyCode))

Another way to check and allow all special keycode can be found by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1720797/3520697). This is a better approach but requires more code.

```
import string

MyNumCtrl = wx.TextCtrl()
MyNumCtrl.Bind(EVT_CHAR, onChar)

def onChar(self, event):
    keycode = event.GetKeyCode()
    obj = event.GetEventObject()
    val = obj.GetValue()
    # filter unicode characters
    if keycode == wx.WXK_NONE:
        pass 
    # allow digits
    elif chr(keycode) in string.digits:
        event.Skip()
    # allow special, non-printable keycodes
    elif chr(keycode) not in string.printable:
        event.Skip() # allow all other special keycode
    # allow '-' for negative numbers
    elif chr(keycode) == '-':
        if val[0] == '-':
            obj.SetValue(val[1:])
        else:
            obj.SetValue('-' + val)
    # allow '.' for float numbers
    elif chr(keycode) == '.' and '.' not in val:
        event.Skip()
    return
```

Answer (score -1):

Please check "Validator.py" script in wxpython demo. it is exactly what you need