# wxPython wx.KeyEvent GetKeyCode()

Tags: wxpython, keypress

I am writing a wxPython app in which I want (at the moment) to print the name of the key that was pressed.  I have a dictionary that maps, for example, the WXK_BACK to "back" which seems a sane.  However, which file must I import (include?) to get the definition of WXK_BACK ?

I have the `import wx` statement, but am unsure which specific file holds the secrets

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All key names can be directly used after importing `wx` module e.g

```
>>> import wx
>>> wx.WXK_BACK 
8
```

also you do not need to generate key to name map by hand, you generate keycode to name mapping automatically e.g.

```
import wx

keyMap = {}
for varName in vars(wx):
    if varName.startswith("WXK_"):
        keyMap[varName] = getattr(wx, varName)

print keyMap
```

Then in OnChar you can just do this

```
def OnChar(self, evt):
    try:
        print keyMap[evt.GetKeyCode()]
    except KeyError:
        print "keycode",evt.GetKeyCode(), "not found"
```

Comment: Thank you!
That is easier, AND I learned something.  I appreciate your all your help.
:bp:

Answer (score 0):

You only need to import wx for the WXK_BACK symbol.  Code that looks something like the following should work.

```
import wx

class MyClass( wx.Window ):
    def __init__(self):
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CHAR, self.OnChar)
    def OnChar(self, evt):
        x = evt.GetKeyCode()
        if x==wx.WXK_BACK:
            print "back"
```

Comment: Thanks!  I am still a bit new to this python/wxpython, and the wx. prefix eluded me.  (I was using WXK_BACK rather than wx.WXK_BACK).
Thank you very much for your help.

:bp: